# Achieving lower volume settings/finer volume tuning with Turtle Beach DAC

Tags: windows-7, audio

I recently purchased a driverless usb audio card (Turtle Beach Advantage Micro II).
It outputs audio in great quality, but also in a volume that high that I need to set the system volume on its lowest level and use my audio player volume controls.

Is there anyway to get finer control on the native system volume?

EDIT: I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/207588/improve-granularity-of-volume-controls-in-windows-7) similar to mine. 
One of the answers provide a way of setting higher volume granularity.

EDIT 2: Tried it but couldn't achieve any higher granularity.

Comment: Why dont you just lower the volume on your audio card?

Comment: It doesn't have any volume control, it's a simple sound card, merely meant to output audio in higher quality than most on-board drivers.

Comment: In Windows Volume Mixer's volmue bar, there are 100 steps, a volume bar with 1,000 steps could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

While this card is sold as driverless audio card, [optional drivers from Turtle Beach](http://www.turtlebeach.com/support/index.php?View=files&CategoryID=424) normalize its volume to a normal level.